# How do I use third party versions of appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am using the `github/golang/appengine` package in a Go website. I was under the impression I need to use "goapp" in order to use Datastore locally. Fine and dandy. goapp build my code ok, but I keep getting

```
ERROR    2014-05-10 17:15:18,875 http_runtime.py:262] bad runtime process port ['']

panic: proto: duplicate enum registered: appengine.ModulesServiceError_ErrorCode
```

I tried aliasing the appengine packages, and I still get this error. Does anyone know why I am getting this error? Let me know whatever code you need to see.

Comment: I have no clue what you do or want to do. You are running code on the Google managed VMs Preview?

Comment: What I want to do is run a version of "appengine" using actual "go get" packages in a website. For one thing, using

import "appengine"

doesn't work very well with my IDE's intellisense. What I really wish I could do is treat an "appengine"&"appengine/datastore" package like any other and write Go code with it without running my code with "goapp serve".

Comment: Still can't work out what you are trying to do.

Comment: So you have asked this question before.  Are you trying to run a local datastore and use that as a production website ?  The SDK backend is written in python and won't scale.  Appscale have an alternate backend, but support for go appears to be out of date.

Comment: What I want is to be able to use a package like "google.golang.org/appengine" like I would any other.

Comment: Or without App Engine SDK complaining about it

Comment: Maybe this will clarify things...

import (
 "fmt"
 ap "google.golang.org/appengine"
 data "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore"
 "html/template"
 "log"
 "net/http"
 "os"
 "sdklessdatastoremusic/config"
 "sdklessdatastoremusic/model"
 "strconv"
 "strings"
)

That compiles just fine with "go build", but "goapp serve" doesn't seem to like it.

Comment: Running a build gives me "NewContext passed an unknown http.Request" , and "goapp serve" gives me " duplicate enum registered: appengine.ModulesServiceError_ErrorCode"

Comment: Let's ask again: Why do you want to import that package? Are you shure you did understand the purpose of golang/appengine? (See my first comment)

Comment: Well, people are creating "appengines" as normal packages, and I'm wondering why people would create such things if they're useless.

Comment: Sorry if I seem offensive or strange. I'm pretty isolated as a programmer, and I have an outdated formal education (Bachelors in 1990, no Masters)... so since I was never formally taught 21st century orthodoxy I tend to go outside it.

Comment: "Managed VMs" is a new, not publicly released feature of appengine that lets you run code without the same constraints as "normal" appengine. This package is for people using that. If you're not, then it won't be useful to you, but that's different from it being useless.

Comment: This is no "appengine" -> Read the description. It makes it possible to use appengine services from an managed VM. Both running on the Google infrastructure. That's what the package description says. If you look into internal/datastore for example: There is not Datastore implementation, just the calls to the Appengine Datastore (using Protobuf).
Why didn't you take my questions seriously?

Answer (score 3):

You are getting that panic because you are mixing traditional App Engine and Managed VMs. You can't do that. The `google.golang.org/appengine` packages are only for Managed VMs; if you aren't using Managed VMs then you need to stick with importing `appengine` or `appengine/datastore` or similar.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know I was trying to do something that's impossible in the normal scheme of things. Now all I need to figure out is how to undo "go get"s. No sense in packages I can't use taking up real estate.

Comment: Now they are for classic appengine too. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11670